# Unable to open file in r modefatal

Tags: command-line

Through terminal, I am trying to execute a program . I have to mention a file which is present in another folder while writing the execute command.

I have one folder in which my executable resides. That folder name is **apps**. and the file which I want to mention along with the execute command is residing in another folder named **"dataset**". This folder is in apps folder.

Rightnow , I am in apps folder

and run this command

```
./executable -i ./dataset/filename
```

but this gives me this error though the file is present in dataset folder:

```
Unable to open file in r mode fatal
```

Comment: Please add, which executable you are trying to run. Not all executables can handle a relative path, have you tried with full path? And please check if your program is allowed to read the file. (I had rare cases where I ran a programm on files in sudo mode, but the files where just readable by the user.)

Comment: I gave the full path but still same error appears

Comment: Try using `perror` instead of displaying the generic error message "Unable to open file in r mode fatal".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your `executable` do, I think that you should specify the full path for `dataset/filename`:

```
./executable -i /path/to/dataset/filename
```

For example, if `dataset/filename` is in your home directory, you can use:

```
./executable -i ~/dataset/filename
```

or:

```
./executable -i /home/<your_user_name>/dataset/filename
```

Comment: I did all this but still the same error is appearing.

Comment: @Zara Then what does your `executable`? Is a script? Did you downloaded from somewhere? If yes, from where?

Comment: No, its a simple C program whose executable I made. Now I just put that file in apps folder from where I was running the executable but still the same error appears.

Comment: @Zara Then can you show us that simple C program? Because sure there is a problem. You can past it on http://paste.ubuntu.com/